# How to merge 2 arrays into 1 array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to merge my array into one while creating different objects inside it.
The result I want to achieve is:

```
[{latitude: 19.04890787659077,longitude: 47.49627131324106}, {latitude: 19.07438856746581, longitude: 47.49834420053164}, {etc..}]
```

My current arrays look like this:

```
0: 19.04890787659077
1: 18.93150306374864
2: 18.570734077493597
3: 17.948338720442376
4: 18.594379058124062

0: 47.49627131324106
1: 47.44522085405608
2: 47.482922755413774
3: 47.31701880320728
4: 46.052752331223935
```

The data will be dynamic so I can't solve it by [{latitude: Arr[0], longitude: Arr[5]}, {etc..}]

Comment: Please show what you code you used to get that result, so we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr1 = [
  19.04890787659077,
  18.93150306374864,
  18.570734077493597,
  17.948338720442376,
  18.594379058124062
];
const arr2 = [
  47.49627131324106,
  47.44522085405608,
  47.482922755413774,
  47.31701880320728,
  46.052752331223935
];

const result = arr1.map((v, i) => ({
  latitude: v,
  longitude: arr2[i]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you meant but I think you are looking for one of these:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr1,arr2);
```

or

```
arr1 = arr1.concat(arr2)
```

These are the old school methods, the new way to do it is

```
var arr3 = [...arr1, ...arr2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one array like this:

```
const a = [19, 18, 17, 18, 19, 47, 46, 46, 47, 47];
```

I tried this:

```
const mid = Math.floor(a.length/2);
const result = a.slice(0, mid).map((el, idx) => ({lat:el, lon:a[idx+mid]}))
```